# Why does the year 2038 problem occur in the first place?

Tags: timestamps, 32bit

I've seen many questions on stack overflow about why some code isn't working with times beyond the year 2038, but the answers usually only recommend to upgrade to a 64 bit operating system. My question is why does this occur in the first place? Is it similar to the year 2000 problem? Could it be fixed with a different operating system, or are 32-bit processors physically incapable of handling times past 2038? Why? (I'm new to linux so this might be an easy question but I really don't know the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Time un Unix systems is tracked by the number of seconds since the Epoch, 00:00 on 1 Jan 1970 UTC.  At one point in 2038, that number of seconds will exceed the ability of a 32-bit integer to store.  This is why 64-bit kernels resolve the issue. Quoth [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

> The Unix time_t data type that represents a point in time is, on many platforms, a signed integer, traditionally of 32 bits (but see below), directly encoding the Unix time number as described in the preceding section. Being 32 bits means that it covers a range of about 136 years in total. The minimum representable date is Friday 1901-12-13, and the maximum representable date is Tuesday 2038-01-19. One second after 03:14:07 UTC 2038-01-19 this representation will overflow. This milestone is anticipated with a mixture of amusement and dread—see year 2038 problem.
>
> In some newer operating systems, time_t has been widened to 64 bits. This expands the times representable by approximately 293 billion years in both directions, which is over twenty times the present age of the universe per direction.

Further reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: On a side-note: A program running on a 32 bit processor is actually able to handle 64 bit time-stamps. The compiler breaks down the 64 bit arithmetic so it can be executed on 32 bit processors. It is totally doable, albeit slow. So while the processor in itself is incapable of doing 64 arithmetic, this limitation can be overcome by software.

Comment: @Hermann It's a bit more complicated than that. Of course a 32-bit processor can perform 64-bit computations, or even use bigints with thousands of digits. The problem is that the Posix data type `time_t` is an "arithmetic" type, i.e. you are able to add and subtract values from it using C's + and - operators. In standard C (including older versions that should be supported) the largest integer is long, which, for legacy reasons, is typically stuck at 32 bits on 32-bit platforms. This is what all the fuss about the 2038 problem is about.

Comment: If course, there are a billion archive media in various places which contain 32-bit dates, and will require legacy systems to retrieve them in less than 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why does this occur in the first place?

Because the maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer is 2147483647, which is the amount of seconds in a bit more than 68 years. So, with the start point at 1970, the range of a signed 32-bit integer counting seconds runs out in 2038.

> Is it similar to the year 2000 problem?

In a sense. Y2K was about having reserved space for only two decimal digits, this is about having only reserved 32 bits.

> Could it be fixed with a different operating system

Sure. E.g. Windows uses a 64-bit value counting 100 ns ticks since 1601 for NTFS; that should be enough until the year 30 828.

> or are 32-bit processors physically incapable of handling times past 2038?

No, it's just that a 32-bit number is not enough. The programs running on 32-bit processors can handle bigger numbers by using more than one 32-bit word and some logic; that's how the huge numbers needed in cryptography are handled. (I do also wonder if this 32-bit time format was first even used on 32-bit or 16-bit machines (or some weirder ones).)

At this point, it's "only" a compatibility issue since a lot of/most existing software (on 32-bit systems) assumes 32-bit timestamps, and the operating system interfaces provide that. Building a new system that used 64-bit timestamps would be easy, but doing that in a way that's compatible with older software is significantly harder. (But AFAIK, support for 64-bit time on 32-bit Linux has been added, or is being worked on.)